# MS Access Use multiple subqueries in query

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a problem.

I want to get the COUNT of 3 tables where a Name is like 'La', So I created this query:

```
SELECT COUNT(a.ID), COUNT(b.ID), COUNT(c.ID)
FROM (SELECT * FROM Artists WHERE Artistname LIKE "La*")  a, (SELECT * FROM Albums WHERE Name LIKE "La*")  b, (SELECT * FROM Songs WHERE Name LIKE "La*")  c
```

This returns me 3 times 0, but when I just run one of the subqueries I get this result:

```
SELECT * FROM Artists WHERE Artistname LIKE "La*"
```

Returns 1...

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Return the 3 columns like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Artists WHERE Artistname LIKE "La*")  countA, 
  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Albums WHERE Name LIKE "La*")  countB, 
  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Songs WHERE Name LIKE "La*")  countC
FROM Artists
```

Or:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
  COUNT(*) countA, 
  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Albums WHERE Name LIKE "La*")  countB, 
  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Songs WHERE Name LIKE "La*")  countC
FROM Artists
WHERE Artistname LIKE "La*"
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the expressions in the `SELECT`:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as artist_cnt,
       (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Albums WHERE Name LIKE "La*") as album_cnt,
       (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Songs WHERE Name LIKE "La*") as song_cnt
FROM (SELECT COUNT(*) as artist_cnt
      FROM Artists
      WHERE Artistname LIKE "La*"
     ) as a;
```

Well, all but the first `COUNT()`.  MS Access requires something in the `FROM` clause, so it is tricky to move all of them to the `SELECT`.

Answer (score 0):

If you perform the count within the subqueries, each subquery will return exactly **one record**, meaning that you can then output the results using a cross-join or cartesian product, e.g.:

```
select a.c1, b.c2, c.c3
from
    (select count(*) as c1 from artists where artists.artistname like "La*") a,
    (select count(*) as c2 from albums where albums.name like "La*") b,
    (select count(*) as c3 from songs where songs.name like "La*") c
```